# Customising the style of a document library/list

Tags: list, css, libraries, style

I am trying to change the default styling for some of my document libraries and lists.

I've got a decent understanding of CSS and HTML, but never in the SharePoint sphere.

What is the best way in which to alter the style of document libraries?

At the moment I have a CSS file in my sites assest library with the styling I want, but I am not sure how to create the link between this and the libraries I want it to alter?

I am using SP2013

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the style library is a good place to store css files.

The reference itself depends on how to you want to have the scope of the changes.

If you are okay with having a global site reference, use the masterpage or the alternatecss property in site settings, masterpage section.

if you want to narrow down the scope, you can add it at the page layout level, or the .aspx page level, individually for each page, which seems to be the case as you appear to want to customize only a specific set of libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I am 100% on this, if I have  a CSS file in my style library or assets library and I want to have only specific pages inherit those styles I can just go into those pages and put in regular a CSS reference at the top of the page <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style library/asset library">

Comment: that's right. usually on specific pages you will find a place holder called PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead where you can add css and scripts which will go to the head section

Answer (score 1):

In SP2013 you can define a custom ccs file to be linked to your masterpage on your root site via Site Settings => Look and Feel => Masterpage => Alternate CCS URL => Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it.
Click 'Browse' to insert the path to your css file (best location to store it would be the list 'Style Library').